# Is there a way to order the maximal ideals of the ring of integers? Is there an order structure to maximal ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I am looking at the maximal ideals of the ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ and I see that they are precisely the ideals generated by prime numbers, $(p)$, $p$ prime.

For example, 
$(2)=\{...,-4,-2,0,2,4,...\}$

$(3)=\{...,-6,-3,0,3,6,...\}$

$(5)=\{...,-10,-5,0,5,10,...\}$

these are indeed maximal: pick one of them, say $(2)$ and suppose $(m)$ for some prime $m$ contains $(2)$, without $(m)$ being $\mathbb{Z}$ itself. Then by looking at the elements of the example ideals above, we see there is no such $(m)$. We cannot have set inclusion of proper ideals of this form, due to their "prime-ness". One ideal does not divide the other, since they are generated by prime numbers, etc.

Now, this leads me to think about the ordering on these maximal ideals. Is there one? I suppose we could apply a relation < given by "m is larger than n" for two ideals $(m)$ and $(n)$. Then $(2) < (3)$, but this doesn't really mean anything.

Can anyone tell me more about order structure on maximal ideals, particularly these ones?

Comment: The set of all prime ideals of $\mathbb Z$ is called the spectrum of $\mathbb Z$ and is denoted $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb Z)$. Googling 'ordering spec(Z)' yielded nothing for me.

Comment: Yes, it must be that there is ordering we can put on the prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ that actually makes sense. Thanks for that fact about the spectrum though!

Comment: The zero ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ is properly contained in every nonzero prime ideal, but there are no other proper inclusions between prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$. Also, the zero ideal is the only prime ideal that does not contain a prime number, and the only one that is not maximal.